# Join Two tables but replace overlapping data with second tables

Tags: mysql

Hello I have an issue I am working on for a theoretical problem. Assume I have these two tables

Order Table

| Entry | Order# | DatePlaced | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 5 | 2021-05-03 | C |

Status Table

| Entry | Order# | Status | Date | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 5 | S | 2021-05-04 | 0 |
| 2002 | 5 | D | 2021-05-05 | 0 |

So I need to be able to get this

Expected Table

| Entry | Order# | DatePlaced | Type | Status | Date | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2002 | 5 | 2021-05-03 | C | D | 2021-05-05 | 0 |

This would be fairly easy if I could just left join the data. The is issue is that the sql in the code is already written like this. The tables are joined based on the entry. Every time a new status occurs for an order# the entry in the Order Table is updated EXCEPT when it is delivered. Do to how dependent the code is I cannot simply update the initial query below. I was wondering if there is a join or way without using SET that I can get the last status based on the order? I was thinking we can check the order and then the entry but I am not sure how to join that with the Current Table (data we get from query)

```
SELECT * FROM orders or 
LEFT JOIN status st ON or.entry = st.entry
WHERE st.deleted = 0;
```

This results in this

Current Table

| Entry | Order# | DatePlaced | Type | Status | Date | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 5 | 2021-05-03 | C | S | 2021-05-04 | 0 |

Is there a way to JOIN the status table with the Current Table so that the status columns become what I expect?

Answer (score 1):

This will work just fine:

```sql
SELECT s.entry, s.order_no, o.date_placed, o.type, s.status, s.date, s.deleted 
FROM `orders` o
INNER JOIN `status` s ON (
    s.order_no=o.order_no AND s.entry=(SELECT MAX(entry) FROM status WHERE order_no = o.order_no)
)
```

##### Live Demo

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/twz1TT9VH7YNTY1KrpRAjx/3

Answer (score 0):

Does the last status have a higher entry number or higher date created?

Perhaps include `MAX(st.Entry) as last_entry` in your `SELECT` clause,

Maybe select your fields explicitly
vs SELECT *

and include a

```
GROUP BY
```

after your `WHERE` clause
and a

```
 HAVING
```

after your `GROUP BY`

```
create table orders  ( 
entry INT, 
order_number INT, 
date_placed date, 
order_type  VARCHAR(1) )

create table order_status  (
entry INT,
order_number INT,
order_status VARCHAR(1),
date_created date,
deleted INT
);

INSERT INTO orders (entry, order_number, date_placed, order_type) VALUES (2001, 5, '2021-05-03', 'C');

INSERT INTO order_status (entry, order_number, order_status, date_created, deleted) 
VALUES 
(2001, 5, 'S', '2001-05-04', 0),
(2002, 5, 'D', '2001-05-05', 0);

SELECT os.entry, o.order_number, o.date_placed, o.order_type, 
       os.order_status, os.date_created, os.deleted, 
       MAX(os.entry) as last_entry
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN order_status os
    ON o.order_number = os.order_number
 GROUP BY o.order_number
HAVING os.entry = last_entry
```